# How to create backup from symbolic links and from files, too?

Tags: tar

I would like to archive some directories.
These directories are contain some softlinks.
I should keep these links and files, too.

I didn't found any solution...
I tried `tar` with `-h` option but it keeps just files, but not links.
The simple `-cf` neither.

Comment: Your question is not clear. `tar` archives all files including symlinks by default, and `-h` makes it archive symlinks' targets instead of the symlinks, so by a process of elimination I guess you want to archive both symlinks and their targets. Is that it?

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes... 1st of all... my english is poor.
2nd I never learned programming... I'm quite newbie in coding and it seems sometimes harder to ask a question, like find the right answer.
I'm sorry and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbolic links are pointers to files in a filesystem. You may want to try to use the `--dereference` option with `tar`.

This asks `tar` to create copies of the data that the symbolic links point to.

Here is the [documentation from gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/dereference.html)

```
When `--dereference' (`-h') is used with `--create' (`-c'), 
tar archives the files symbolic links point to, instead of the links themselves.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the symlinks on the target machine manually in this case.

On the source machine use **tar cvhf** (or czvhf). when extracting on the target, the files find their way to the right location, if the symlinks exist.

If they do not exist, tar the symlinks separately with **tar cvf** and extract on the target **before** extracting the rest of the files, archived with **tar cvhf**.